# Speeds and feeds -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJ16Njh-5JE&index=43&list=PLaPygi1zEFDol1N_YbwvZirr075k6SLQ4

> In this module, we've been discussing Ethernet. We began by talking about the history of Ethernet. Remember? It was developed by Xerox back in 1972 and it's come a long way since then. We talked about some of the different **speeds and feeds**. Some of the different media that we might use to transmit Ethernet.

Alright, he did talk about different data speed options offered by Ethernet technology during the module, but I'm at a complete loss as to what he means by feeds. Is this some sort of expression he's using?

Comment: [*On the World Wide Web, a **web feed** (or **news feed**) is a data format used for providing users with frequently updated content.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed) But I wouldn't over-think the usage - the speaker almost certainly chose to use those two words primarily for their alliterative effect, not the relevance of their *meaning*. The collocation [does have significance in metalwork/engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeds_and_feeds), but this has nothing to do with your context.

Comment: Ethernet is not transmitted. So, right there, I see a problem. Ethernet is a network over which packets are transmitted. These videos can be very bad indeed.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r30857827-Ethernet-Feed-Between-Properties) help? Sometimes the connection is called a feed, I think? Though I also agree somewhat with @FumbleFingers that the speaker used the two words together because they rhyme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As FumbleFingers mentions in his comment the use of "speeds and feeds" is used for the way it *sounds* more than what it actually *means*.

"Speeds" refers to various upload/download capacities, from old-fashioned dial-up to full ["Internet2"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet2) connections.  In this case the context is the various options available to transmit over Ethernet networks.

"Feeds" refers to the various ways data can be transmitted over the Internet in standard formats, such as [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).  This is really only a small part of the data passed over the Internet, and is only indirectly related to Ethernet in the same way roads are indirectly related to automobiles.

Comment: This expression is probably related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeds_and_feeds